# Git Merge --no-ff makes copy of commits

Tags: git, merge, fast-forward

I had a curious git behaviour today, and I want to ask if this is normal. Now, this is the situation (new commits are added to the bottom):

```
br1  br2
  A
    \ 
     B
     C
     D
```

Now, when I make

```
git checkout br1
git merge --no-ff br2
```

It becomes like this (please read up to down; newest commit is 'E')

```
br1  br2
  A
  | \ 
  |  B
  |  C
  |  D
  | /
  E
```

OK.. Now, weird thing is; now I call "git status"; it says I'm 4 commits ahead of the remote branch. How is this happening? Shouldn't I be only one commit ahead?

And the peculiar thing is, when I check from the Stash (the Git Web UI, basically) it confirms this "4 commits" status and I see the same commits (B C and D) under "br1" and "br2" both...

I assumed when I used "--no-ff" parameters, the commits at "br2" (B C D) won't be copied to the "br1" and only merge commit created. Am I mistaken here?

Comment: Using ABCD instead of 0 would be more informative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the 4 commits are actually part of `br1`. If you delete `br2`, the commits will still be part of `br1`. The difference comes when you are resetting the merge commit. If you do a hard reset you will go back to the commit just before the merge commit i.e. `E`. This is especially useful when you want to rollback. So yes, you are four commits ahead, but as long as you are not resetting `br1`, you should be fine.

Also `-no-ff` is not to stop git from copying the commits. It is to keep the commits separate from the tree of `br1`. That way you maintain a history of branches and the context in which the commits were made, rather than a mass of commits all related to different features

Comment: In our case, the last commit is E, not A. You are reading the alphabet inverse :)

Anyhow, if what you are saying about --no-ff is right, then me seeing the history of the br2 on Stash is perfectly OK, right? TBH, I was expecting to see only the merge commit A there, not the others.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** The poster changed the question after I composed this answer. This update answers to one of the questions the rest of the answer doesn't cover.

> OK.. Now, weird thing is; now I call "git status"; it says I'm 4 commits ahead of the remote branch. How is this happening? Shouldn't I be only one commit ahead?

After you merged (`--no-ff`) the commits `A` and `D` into `E`, the local branch is 4 commits ahead of the remote branch (I suppose the remote branch still points to `A`). This is correct.

Let's count the commits that are on the local branch (now pointing to `E`) and aren't on the remote branch (pointing to `A`). `E` is obviously one of them. `E`, being a merge commit, has two parents: `A` (existing on the remote branch) and `D` (not existing on the remote branch). When `git` pushes `E` to the remote server it needs to push both its parents (otherwise `E` is invalid on the remote server).

`D` requires `C` (its parent) that requires `B` that requires `A`. `A` already exists on the remote server and the chain ends here. `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` do not exist on the remote server. All of them must be pushed in order to keep the consistency of the data on the remote server.

---

*The rest of the response treats the original question that was not very clear defined. The poster made references to `git log --graph` and (probably) [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server). Both these tools (and all the other `git` interfaces I know) present the most recent commit first in the commit history. This answer uses the same convention.*

[`git merge --no-ff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) doesn't have any effect in the situation you described.

Having `br1` as current branch, `git merge br2` brings into `br1` the changes introduced by the commits that are reachable from `br2` and are not reachable from `br1`. Depending on the relative position of `br1` regarding `br2`, `git merge` can create a new commit (that contains all the changes introduced by the commits unreachable from `br1`) or it can just move the `br1` branch head into a new position (and doesn't create any new commit).

In your situation, `br2` is behind `br1` with 1 commit and because `A` is a merge commit, all the commits accessible from `br2` can also be reached from `br1`.

---

Anyway, `git merge --no-ff` is used in a different situation.

Let's say we have this graph:

```
 B <-- br2
 |
 C
 |
 D
 |
 E <-- br1
 |
...
```

The branch `br2` was created from branch `br1` (both were at commit `E` at that time) then `br2` was checked out and three new commits (`D`, `C` and `B`) were added.

In this situation, the commands:

```
git checkout br1
git merge br2
```

do not create a new branch. The branch `br1` is moved to commit `B` (where `br2` is) and that's all. Now all the commits that are reachable from `br2` are also accessible from `br1`. `br2` was successfully merged into `br1`.

This is how the graph looks like:

```
br1 --> B <-- br2
        |
        C
        |
        D
        |
        E
        |
       ...
```

This kind of merge is called `fast-forward` because the branch `br1` was moved "fast forward" from its previous position to a new position (probably opposed to branch `b2` that moved from `E` to `B` one commit at a time). It is possible only if `br2` is the only one child path of `br1` (starting from `E`, each commit has a single child commit and the path reaches `B`).

Here comes `--no-ff` into play. If you want this merge to create a merge commit that contains all the changes introduced by commits `D`, `C` and `B` then you run:

```
git checkout br1
git merge --no-ff br2
```

The presence of `--no-ff` option prohibits the fast forwarding of branch `b1` and forces the creation of a new merge commit. The graph will look like this:

```
 A <-- br1
 |\
 | B <-- br2
 | |
 | C
 | |
 | D
 |/
 E
 |
...
```

Comment: Hate to say it, but you read the history inverse... In my graph, new commits are added to the bottom, not top... This is precisely my question: your answer is already what I am expecting but not the case. When I wrote the --no-ff; system still says "4 commits ahead" not "1 commit ahead"...

Comment: I read the history as it is presented by all the `git` interfaces I know, including `git log --graph` **and** [Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/server), i.e. the most recent commit comes first. Your graph is upside down for a reason only you know. I updated the answer with the explanation why your local branch is 4 commits ahead the remote branch.

Comment: Then can you please explain to me, how could I be adding commits to the back in the history in this context of question? My language is read left to right, top to bottom; so I did use that convention; even used alphabetical letters in order to show the precedence... Anyway, still, thank you for the answer but you answered the wrong question; not mine, when you first posted this.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding how branches work in Git. [Branches are lightweight](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is), which means nothing gets copied when you create a new branch or merge one branch into another.

A branch is a reference that *points* to a commit. Since every commit is linked to its previous commits, when you point to one commit you are effectively pointing to the *history* of that commit.

In your example, `E` is a merge commit that *combines* two branches together, creating a single history. This means that after merging `br2` into `br1`, `br1` (which is **now** a reference to `E`) will know about the history of `br2` (which is **still** a reference to `D`), because `D`, `C` and `B` are part of the history of `E`.

Your local `br1` is a reference to `E`, while your remote `br1` is still a reference to `A`. Therefore, there are four commits (`B`, `C`, `D` and `E`) that are *new* to the history of `br1`.

Comment: OK, let me rephrase then: Why does br1 reference to the B C and D? Should it not only refer to the E (the merge commit) ? When I check the status, it says "4 commits ahead", not "1 commit ahead". It makes me confused, it is as if the Git pushed the same commits to the server again (commits have same hashes though).

Comment: I just checked, that the Stash does it all the time; and since it shows everything linearly, it is the cause of confusion. I guess I have to make everyone use git log --graph instead of the Stash history then :)

Comment: `br1` is a reference to `E`. This means it knows about `B`, `C` and `D` as well. This is because `E` has two parents: `A` and `D`; `D` has one parent: `C`; `C` has one parent: `B`; `B` has one parent: `A`. Therefore, `E` links `A` and `D` together.